# Is the I - IV - vi - IV music progression common in pop music?

Tags: chord-progressions, pop-music

So I just started studying music theory, so for fun I thought I would practice by analyzing a song I remember enjoying. Marianas Trench's satirical song "Pop 101":

The song suggests using the chord progression I - IV - vi - IV. Because the song is a satire, I assumed this meant they think the chord progression was overly used in pop. However, I'm struggling to find any examples of songs using it. The progression I - V - vi - IV seems much more common, and I know how to square this with "common practice". I don't know how to make sense of "IV - vi" step with my beginner text.

Is it possible they made a mistake and ran with it? Or are there a ton of songs in I - IV - vi - IV that I'm just failing to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This parody is very clever for sure. There are plenty of V chords in it though. I also can’t think of one tune offhand that uses that specific 1-4-6-4 combination. Replace either 4 with a 5 and you might have something there. Maybe they used the last “4” to get a false rhyme at 0:40 with “familiar” (familior?). A very large number of pop tunes use various combinations of I,IV,V,vi, which you pointed out. It seems to be the winning combination these days.

Comment: Okay, so I'm not crazy. I was sorta excited to be in on the joke, I'm a little sad I'm still not in on the joke XD

Comment: I mentioned something about a joke in my answer at first (maybe they did 1-4-6-4 as a joke) but decided to take it out. Is that what you mean? Either way, you’re in on it!

Comment: I mean I was looking forward to understanding this song lyrics and "getting the joke". But they went and threw a curve ball! Not fair!

Answer (score 1):

[Hook theory](https://www.hooktheory.com/trends) has a nice database, which you can search by chord progression. It displays the corresponding songs, and the probabilities for the following chords.

[Here](https://www.hooktheory.com/trends#node=1.4.6.4.1&key=rel) are some results for I, IV, vi, IV, I.

[image]

I checked a few of the above songs (e.g. "What the hell" by Avril Lavigne, "Adam's song" by Blink 182, "Just Give Me A Reason" by Pink) and they indeed contain I, IV, vi, IV, I (e.g. C, F, Am, F, C). It's possible to select the key of the song but I just left it at "Relative".

If you look for [I, V, vi, IV](https://www.hooktheory.com/trends#node=1.5.6.4.1&key=rel) instead, you get *a lot* of corresponding songs. Some of them were used in ["Axis of Awesome - Four Chords"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pidokakU4I).